# MS Access Forms datasheet to populate all matching records in a dropdown from another table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using MS Access 2013 forms.

I have 2 tables: `TblA` and `TblB`.

Both have multiple references and values and what I am trying to do is have a datasheet of `TblB` and have a combobox on the same datasheet which will show the field `OrigAmt` from `TblA` that matches `TblB`.

The purpose of this is because there is no link between the tables other than the reference the user will need to see all values so they can select the value that is in `TblA` that relates to that record and then `TblA` will update with values from `TblB`.

I tried using the lookup field on rowsource from the design where the reference from `TblA` equals `TblB` but the datasheet doesn't seem to filter on a row level.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TblA.Reference, TblA.OriginalAmount
FROM TblA INNER JOIN TblB ON TblA.Reference = TblB.Reference
```

I'm sure this has probably been answered before but I cant seem to work this out after spending hours on this.

Comment: But aren't you trying to get all references from tblA in order to set the reference? Surely you need "SELECT DISTINCT TblA.Reference, TblA.OriginalAmount
FROM TblA"

Comment: only the references that match table b because there can be many of the same reference in tblA and this is why i am using the amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working but it is a bit ugly, I have used 2 subforms within a mainform added a textbox on my mainform to capture what is selected from the subform (TblB) also doing the same for TblA. On the second subform (TblA data) I manually typed the reference into the Link Master/Child fields. Finally I then added an update query to update TblA with TblB data. Hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you are asking. First, you need to get the selected Reference number to work with. The easiest way to do that is to add a textbox to your form that contains the Reference (`Control Source = Reference`) and let's name that textbox "CurrentReference".
You can hide this textbox if you don't want the user to see it.

Now simply add a where clause to your SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TblA.Reference, TblA.OriginalAmount
FROM TblA WHERE TblA.Reference = CurrentReference
```

Now change your combobox `Enabled = False` so the user can't manually manipulate it.  The combobox now only shows the original amount that corresponds to the selected record in TblB.

NOTE: Now that you are displaying only one value, you can use a TextBox and not a ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks but the user will need to specify the amount as there is no distinct/unique reference (many to many relationship). Currently the subform will show all the records from TblB and has a combobox in the last row of Tbla data (datasheet view) I have the column count to 2 so the user can see the reference and amount but I don't want the selection to every reference only the one that relates to the currentrow).

Comment: Ok, I think I see. Your problem is "Data Sheet View". This view needs to be hidden from the user facing version. You must construct proper forms for your users. You can make a form that prominently displays a data grid, which is the view that people may want. I tried your example with my data and it works. The query returns the expected list. Have you put it in to a query and just viewed it? Then you can simply cite the query name in any element where you want that list to appear.

Comment: Sorry not sure how to create a data grid, I have since made TblB as a subform and added an unbound to a Mainform with a hidden unbound textbox using     =[TblB_SF].[Form]![Reference] but I don't know how to get the unbound combobox on my subform to call the textbox. I will look into trying to make a datagrid so I can try your way, please bear with me. thanks. I can add a simple dropbox file of what I'm trying to achieve.